# For-loop where the step-value is greater than one

Tags: swift, for-loop

In Swift, is there a way to create a for-loop with a step-value greater than one?

In Java, it would be:

```
for(int i = 0; i < 10; i += 2){
    System.out.println(i);
}
```

The only way I've found is using a while-loop.

```
var i = 1
while i < 10 {
    print(i)
    i = i + 2
}
```

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You can achieve this in Swift using the `stride(from:to:by:)` function like this:

```
for i in stride(from: 0, to: 9, by: 2) {
    print(i)
}
```

Or using a `forEach` closure:

```
stride(from: 0, to: 9, by: 2).forEach {
    print($0)
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Update for Swift-3 syntax

```
for i in stride(from:0, to: 20, by: 5) {
    print(i)
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use `stride`

```
0.stride(through: 10, by: 2).forEach {
    print($0)
}

/* 0
   2
   4
   6
   8
   10 */
```